# Wilson lines with Chan-Paton factors in string theory

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, yang-mills, branes, wilson-loop

In the context of compactifying the open string with Chan-Paton factors, Polchinski (Volume I Section 8.6) considers a toy example with a point particle of charge $q$ which has the action

$$ S = \int d \tau \left( \frac{1}{2} \dot{X}^M \dot{X}_M + \frac{m^2}{2} - i q A_M \dot{X}^M \right) \tag{8.6.3}$$

where $M=0,...,25$ is running over all the 26 dimensions and the last dimension is compactified $X^{25} \sim X^{25}+ R$. He then argues that taking the locally pure gauge $$A_{25} = - \frac{\theta}{2 \pi R},\tag{8.6.1}$$ paths that wind around the last dimension pick a phase equal to the Wilson line $$e^{-i q \theta}.\tag{8.6.2}$$

Then he moves on to the string with $U(N)$ Chan-Paton factors, and says that the previous story generalizes by diagonalizing $A_{25}$ and considering $$A_{25} = - \frac{1}{2 \pi R} \mathrm{diag}(\theta_1,...,\theta_N).\tag{8.6.8}$$

My question is, how does this generalize? Later he mentions that the open string worlsheet action should contain the gauge field background as
$$S_P \supset i \int_{\partial M} dX^\mu A_\mu .\tag{8.7.6}$$

How would we interpret this in the $U(N)$ case ? Does this become a trace ? Also, now there are two worldlines, one for each endpoint of the open string, doesn't this affect our previous discussion where we only considered a point particle?